# "BeforeInstallPrompt" is only firing after Lighthouse Audit

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, quasar-framework, quasar, beforeinstallprompt

I'm writing a small PWA and I'm trying to add an install banner to the page in VueJS/QuasarJS. In the first step, I'm trying to catch if the beforeinstallprompt is firing, with the following code:

```js
mounted() {
  console.log("mounting"); // works

  window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", (e) => {
    console.log(e); // this only fires during Lighthouse Audit
    e.preventDefault();
    this.deferredPrompt = e;
    console.log(`'beforeinstallprompt' event was fired in mounted.`) // only during Lighthouse Audit
  })
};
```

Whenever I load the app, it is not firing at all. But then I tried to run a Lighthouse Audit in Chrome Dev Tools, suddenly it worked! Also, Lighthouse shows that the PWA is installable. But when I do exactly the same thing without Lighthouse, it is not working. So, what is Lighthouse doing that I'm missing...?

Compiling, I've tried two ways but both show same result (only works after I run Lighthouse):

- Development build: quasar dev -m pwa --> runs on localhost
- Deployed: quasar build -m pwa, firebase deploy --> deployed on firebase

I tried both Firefox and Chrome on Desktop and Android, all with same result. Please if you have an idea, let me know.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You are testing the install with HTTPS ? That is a requirement.

Comment: Hi Mathias, thanks a lot for your reply. yes, the deployed version is running with HTTPS. I tested a bit more and noticed that it is working sometimes and sometimes not. I don't really know why, but I'll leave it like that for now...